# Altering the Bootstrap Gridsystem

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So currently this is how my website layout looks, its of the following order

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
             col-md-3 left
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
             element 1 
             <br/>
             element 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             col-md-3 right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But i want the `element 2` to be in a new div of class `col-md-6` so that it stacks up perfectly after the `col-md-3`, this is how i want it to be

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
             col-md-3 left
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
             element 1 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             col-md-3 right
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        element 2
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i use this code this is what i get.

[image]

How would i achieve the pic1 with a div class `col-md-6` set to element2

**I want the element2 with the class `col-md-6` right between the two `col-md-3` div's**

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question, where exactly do you want element 2 to line up? You said "stacks up perfectly after the col-3" but there are two col-3s on your page. Could you possibly rename them and add a bit of description?

Comment: @ultifinitus : i want the `element2` to come after `col-md-3 right` when i test it on a mobile device, which can only be achieved if i set a separate div to `element2`. But the problem here is the lengths of  col-md-3 are more and if i apply a new div to element2 say `col-md-6` it'll start right after the row has ended.

Comment: Oh! Well a `div` is a block element, which means it is meant to have a line all to itself. Give me just a minute and I'll check out a fix for bootstrap. I usually just do my own css so it may take me a minute or two but I've got you covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a custom class with the desired width to the div `element2` so that it comes down.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so this depends on the makeup of the content of your elements it *could* be as simple as changing this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     element 1 
     <br/>
     element 2
</div>
```

Into this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="tophalf">
        element 1 
     </div>
     <div class="bottomhalf">
        element 2
     </div>
</div>
```

Which would successfully divide your elements, however this adds several other issues. Depending on the nature of your elements you could have problems with the col-md-3 content stretching to the bottom of the element 2. To solve this you can set the height of the outside columns (using a #tag in your css and an id="" in your html) there are many many many questions on that topic, here are a couple:

[First Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548360/inner-div-to-have-height-100-inside-a-container-of-height-auto)

[Second More Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent)

[Another Possibly Relevant Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

I managed to get a quick example up and running if you would like to see the code, but I bet you can figure it out from the info above. Sorry I don't have more information for you- I hope you get another answer that helps more!

Comment: need some time to figure this out, Will update the post if it works thx

Comment: could you link me to an example or something ? im kinda lost !